# How to linearize pdf with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, linearization

How can I [linearize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51711_01/TSG/FAQ/What%20are%20linearized%20PDF%20files_.html) (web-optimize) a random [pdf](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/rogoff/files/growth_in_time_debt_aer.pdf) with `ghostscript` (v9.18)? I know there is `qpdf`, but I want to explicitly use `gs`.

Doing it with this command leads to a broken pdf which I am unable to open:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dFastWebView -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=test.pdf -dBATCH growth_in_time_debt_aer.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then perhaps you should report this as a bug ? Clearly a broken PDF is not intended behaviour, and the documentation is (to me at least) clear that the -dFastWebView switch is used to control linearisation.

Of course, **why** you would bother escapes me, very few viewers actually do anything useful with a linearised file, it can only improve the loading of the first page anyway, its incompatible with later versions of the specification, and it makes the file larger.....